# No carga las categorias en Category.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un CPT y cada post tiene categorías y sub categorías. 
Cuando entro a la pagina de Category.php no me imprime ningún post.

```
    <?php  get_header(); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 float-left mt-3">
        <h1>Category <span><?php single_cat_title(); ?></span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pro" class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 float-left">
    <?php
        get_sidebar();
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 float-left">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
    <?php the_title();?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, todo se debía mostrar en `taxonomy.php`.
Segundo, solo debía actualizar los enlaces permanentes y listo.